# Функция, возвращающая дату следующего понедельника

Tags: javascript

Нужна функция - при вызове она каждый раз возвращает дату следущего понедельника.
То есть, первый раз вернет дату следущего, а во второй, соответственно - дату следующего после следующего, и так далее.

```
function getMonday(date) {
    const mon = date;
    mon.setDate(mon.getDate() - (mon.getDay() || 7) + 1);
    return mon.getDate()
};
```

Comment: А что не так, что не работает?

Comment: Эта функция возвращает понедельник нынешней недели,а мне надо получать при вызове понедельник новой недели

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать вот так.

```js
function getMonday(date) {
  const mon = new Date(date);
  const day = mon.getDay();
  mon.setDate(mon.getDate() - day + (day === 0 ? 1 : 8));
  return mon.getDate()
};

for (let i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
  let date = new Date();
  date.setDate(i);
  console.log('result', getMonday(date));
}
```